# NirCmd monitor off not working from php

Tags: php

I am trying to turn off my monitor from a webapp using NirCmd but it's not working:

```
exec('C:/nircmd/nircmd monitor off');
```

Whereas I can mute and unmute the audio with this:

```
exec('C:/nircmd/nircmd mutesysvolume 1');
```

Anyone else has this issue?